# How to parse an XML that has an & in its tag name using XPath in Java?

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

I want to parse an `XML` whose tag contains an `&` for example: `<xml><OC&C>12.4</OC&C></xml>`. I tried to escape `&` to `&amp;` but that didn't fix the issue for tag name (it fixes it for values only), currently my code is throwing an exception, see complete function below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  String xmlString        = "<xml><OC&C>12.4</OC&C></xml>";
  xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
  String path             = "xml";
  InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
  try
  {
    Document xmlDocument            = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);
    XPath xPath                     = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(path);

    System.out.println("Compiled Successfully.");
  }
  catch (SAXException e)
  {
    System.out.println("Error while retrieving node Path:" + path + " from " + xmlString + ". Returning null");
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have access to script that forms xml just add <![CDATA[]]> to tag name

Comment: Actually your `XML` is invalid, read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xml` could not be name of any XML element. So, your XML fragment could never be parsed anyway. Then you could try something like that.

```
<name><![CDATA[<OC&C>12.4</OC&C>]]></name>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I don't think that it is [a legal XML name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name). I'd think about using a regex to replace OC&C to something legal first, and then parse it.

Comment: About processing XML with regexes, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Arian  I don't think Arawak is suggesting he *parse* the document with regex.  He is is suggesting a search and replace, which regex is well suited for. Then parse with the xml parser.

Comment: You cannot safely search&replace an XML document without parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "an XML". It's a non-XML. XML doesn't allow ampersands in names. Therefore, you can't parse it successfully using an XML parser.